# Using GreenSock JS library with Webstorm

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, gsap

I am creating a website with HTML5 in JetBrains Webstorm 6.0.2
For this I want to use the GreenSock JS library but it does not work for me.
I included the GreenSock .js files in the external libraries but I am still not able to use them, I get for example this error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: TimeLineLite is not defined".

This is how I wanted to use the constructor for TimelineLite:

```
var tl = new TimelineLite();
```

Here is an image from my IDE

[image]
Why can I not use this? Or this does not work with Webstorm ?

Comment: There should be no problem using it with Webstorm (I use it myself). The error you quoted used the wrong capitalization (TimeLineLite instead of TimelineLite), so maybe that's it, although your screen capture has it correct. What GreenSock file(s) did you load exactly? TweenMax.min.js? That contains TimelineLite, but if you only loaded TweenLite, that does not have TimelineLite in it.

Comment: Hi @Jack, I use the non minified TweenMax.js file.
I want to use this library but I do not know why I can not get it to work. Everything seems to be ok just that when I use the TweenMax the compiler says that it is not defined.

Comment: Have you contacted the JetBrains folks about it? I know of a guy on their staff that uses TweenMax too, so I'm pretty confident it should work fine. [scratches head]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is how you add autocomplete, code hinting, etc for JS libraries that don't provide enough information for WebStorm to help (this is not a fault of the library, it's just the way JS works):

[image: Downloading libraries in WebStorm]

A "TypeScript stub" is a way of defining the API of a library and really helps WebStorm understand the library better:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/greensock/greensock.d.ts

Also, WebStorm doesn't include that stub file in your project, it keeps it separated into a WebStorm cache so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: prettiest answer I've seen :) How'd you grab that?

Comment: This question and answer solved some autocomplete issues I was having with Angular in Webstorm, thanks!

Comment: Now you have to search for "gsap" in list, not "green". But it works also even now in 2017 :)

Comment: This did not seem to help me. Thoughts?  https://i.imgur.com/z2p70T6.png